# Uso del imperfecto y pretérito

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Uso de los verbos en el tiempo pasado.

> "Recios golpes **sonar** en la puerta".

La frase es de Josefa Martin Garcia.

¿Por qué usa el pretérito en vez del imperfecto?

Comment: I think you should provide a little bit more context than whose the phrase is from. "Recios golpes sonar en la puerta" doesn't make sense. Besides, **sonar** is infinitive, not pretérito. It could be "sonaban" o "sonaron" and then you could ask for the connotations of each.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar tanto el pretérito indefinido

> Recios golpes **sonaron** en la puerta

como el pretérito imperfecto

> Recios golpes **sonaban** en la puerta

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre uno y otro? Ambos son pretéritos (la acción está terminada). El primero, el pretérito indefinido, se utiliza para acciones ya concluidas o para una acción sucedida en mitad de otra acción:

- Los golpes **sonaron** y luego sólo se oyó silencio. -o-
- Los golpes **sonaron** mientras yo veía la televisión.

El segundo, el pretérito imperfecto, se utiliza para acciones pasadas y enfatiza el aspecto de **repetición y continuidad** en el tiempo (en el ejemplo, imagina que los golpes sonaban y sonaban y sonaban... Vamos, que estuvieron sonando durante un cierto tiempo).

Posiblemente la autora de la frase haya elegido el pretérito indefinido sobre el imperfecto para reflejar algo del tipo "los golpes sólo se oyeron una vez" y no "los golpes se estuvieron oyendo por cierto tiempo".

Answer (score -1):

Esto no responde a tu pregunta pero considero que es una aclaración importante, porque creo que aún no tienes muy claros los tiempos verbales.

«Pretérito» e «imperfecto» no son incompatibles entre sí. Préterito=pasado y perfecto o imperfecto puede ser cualquier acción pasada o futura (presente es siempre imperfecto). (Perfecto alude a un hecho puntual; imperfecto es una acción cuyos principio y fin no son precisos.)

- Sonaban: pretérito imperfecto (de indicativo).
- Sonaron: préterito perfecto simple (" ").
- Han sonado: pretérito perfecto compuesto (" ").

Comment: Me gusta la definición que ofrece el DRAE para los diferentes pretéritos. «Prétérito imperfecto: 1. m. Gram. Tiempo que indica una acción o un estado de cosas simultáneos a un instante anterior al momento en que se habla. En indicativo, amaba, temía, vivía; en subjuntivo, amara o amase, temiera o temiese, viviera o viviese.»
Nota que el hecho de que sea imperfecto no tiene nada que ver con si la acción está acabada o no, sino con que sucede simultáneamente con otra. De ahí lo que digo de que sus límites no son precisos.

http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=qMhy4gwIzDXX2O6nrTx3